# Distance from smallest to the largest element in lists (inside a list)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list, `the_list = [[3, 2, 0, 1, 4, 5], [4, 2, 1, 3, 0, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 5, 2, 4, 3, 0]]`.How do I find out the distance from the smallest element to the largest element in the list.For example, for the first sublist in `the_list` the index for the smallest element `0` is `2` and the index for the largest element `5` is `5`. Therefore, the distance between the two indices is `3` Thus I get the following output:

```
3
1
5
0
```

**Edit:** For the last output, it is 0 because the list ends there and assume that  the list only looks for distance in bound to the right

Comment: I don't get how you got that output.  Can you elaborate a bit further please?  Wouldn't you just get 5 for each sub-list?  I'm probably not understanding your problem statement.

Comment: So for the first sublist in `the_list` the index for the smallest element `0` is 2 and the index for the largest element `5` is 5. Therefore, the distance between the two indices is `3`

Comment: Ah ok, so you want the indices.  I understood that to be the actual elements themselves. Thanks.

Comment: @Eninfo in your example, the distance for the last sublist would be `4`, not `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
lst = [[3, 2, 0, 1, 4, 5], [4, 2, 1, 3, 0, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 5, 2, 4, 3, 0]]
[max(s.index(max(s)) - s.index(min(s)), 0) for s in lst]
=> [3, 1, 5, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! For the fourth sublist, the smallest element is at the end of the sublist and since the list ends here the distance would be 0. I only require a distance in bound to the right

Comment: @Eninfo I don't understand your logic, in the question you state that it's the distance between the _indexes_ of the maximum and minimum value, what does it matter if one of the elements is at the end?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>>list(map(lambda x: x.index(max(x)) - x.index(min(x)) if x.index(max(x)) - x.index(min(x)) > 0 else 0 ,l))
[3, 1, 5, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python very much, but the algorithm could be similar to this (in pseudocode):

```
Foreach list in the_list do begin 
    Min:=maxint;
    MinPos:=0;
    Max:=0;
    MaxPos:=0;
    For I := 0 to list.length do begin 
        If list[i] > Max then begin
            Max := list[i];
            MaxPos := i;
        End;
        If list[i] < Min then begin
            Min := list[i];
            MinPos := i;
        End;
    End;
    If MinPos  < MaxPos then
        Write MaxPos - MinPos;
    Elsewhere
        Write 0;
End;
```

(I'm sorry, I wrote this post at the mobile, and I couldn't  format correctly the text).

Comment: No worries, I've fixed the indentation for you, it just needs to be approved by the moderators before it becomes visible.